# Find $ A \in M_n( \mathbb{C})$ such that for every $ B\in M_n( \mathbb{C})$ exists $ b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ A \cdot B \cdot A= b \cdot A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $ A \in M_n( \mathbb{C})$ such that for every $ B\in M_n( \mathbb{C})$ exists $ b \in \mathbb{C}$  such that  $ A \cdot  B \cdot A= b \cdot A$.How to start? I tried to choose some particular $B$ but doesn't work.

Comment: Which "particular $B$" did you choose ? I guess it should work...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  with one nonzero element.

Comment: and what about $B=I$ ??

Comment: Find $A$ is the question. So take $A=0$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe So A^2 = b A. If A is not invertible...what result from that?